# I was sent a .dbf and a .prj for precincts. I need to make this into a shapefile or a maptitude file

Tags: dbf, maptitude

My database file has an area and length to make it a polygon. I also have the projection file to give it a location. I am just missing the geometry. I want to see the actual geometry this file makes?

I am using MAptitude software and I have a trial of ArcGIS online incase I can use that for some type of conversion.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.
The "shapefile" format stores teh geometry in the SHP file. The DBF file stores other data fields for each geometry record but not the actual geometry.
The PRJ or PROJ file stores the projection information (what is the coordinate system/etc).